# QTP is not recording Java application

Tags: java, ui-automation, qtp

I am new to QTP and trying to learning something with QTP.

I have downloaded trail version of QTP 11.5 from HP site and installed the same.

I am trying to record a stand-alone java application which is generally a java webstart based application.

i.e. I have to download JNLP file and from then it can able to launch and I have to do some work on the same.

If i try to record the same, QTP not even showing any traces of recording after I have stopped recording.

Can anybody help me on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Hi in order to automate Java application you must require **Java** add-in as shown in the image above.

In UFT Trail version you will get only **ActiveX**, **Web**, **Visual Basic** Addins.

**FYI:** The image(UFT Add-in manager) shown above is not a trail version , its a fully loaded licensed version (Uploaded for your understanding )

Comment: I have enabled the Java add-in too. But still it is not working

Comment: Could you able to check the java addin checkbox  or Is it  disabled